# Is there any way to run flutter web app in Internet Explorer?

Tags: flutter, dart, internet-explorer, flutter-web

The official doc says flutter doesn't support IE anymore,

but I need to run my flutter web app in Internet Explorer.

Is there any way to run flutter web app in Internet Explorer?

Comment: if they say they dont support IE? i dont think so

Comment: Well, you can just try and see what happens. "We don't support it" just means they won't help you if it doesn't. If you need to run something in IE, good luck for you, *even Microsoft* doesn't support it any more. Tell the person that you don't program for ancient targets. They should get a supported browser.

Comment: @pskink
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web#which-web-browsers-are-supported-by-flutter
I read this docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned by [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) the official [Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web#which-web-browsers-are-supported-by-flutter) says the following:

> ### Which web browsers are supported by Flutter?
>
> #### Flutter web apps can run on the following browsers:
>
> - Chrome (mobile & desktop)
> - Safari (mobile & desktop)
> - Edge (mobile & desktop)
> - Firefox (mobile & desktop)
>
> During development, Chrome (on macOS, Windows, and Linux) and Edge (on Windows) are supported as the default browsers for debugging your app.

So no you cannot run Flutter Web on Internet Explorer (and it will propably never be supported).